# UITextField contents to NSString

Tags: iphone, uitextfield, uitextview

I am currently making an app that uses a single UITextField gain necessary information for the app's functionality.

I have tried textField.text property,, but for some reason the string is empty.

Here's what I have tried:

```
NSString *contents = urlField.text;
NSString *stringFromTextField = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%@", contents];
```

What am I doing wrong?? It would really help if answers were accompanied by code snippets.

Comment: Make sure `urlField` is not nil.

Comment: How did you create `urlField`? Programmatically or in the IB?

Comment: Double check your connects in Interface Builder that your `urlField` is connected to the `UITextField`.

Comment: Also, depending on what you're trying to do, you shouldn't have to alloc an NSString. Just use [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", contents];

Answer (score 1):

The first line should work just fine without the second. Maybe the urlField outlet isn't hooked up to the actual UI control in the NIB?

Answer (score 0):

1. You don't need to change the formats for the string. You can just assign the `text` member to your string.

> NSString *contents = urlField.text;

1. Are you sure you're setting/initializing the urlField.text properly (Is it linked to a Control in IB or are you doing it manually)?
2. Just a small thing: You can as well just use `urlField.text` for further processing because `urlField.text` already is of type [`NSString`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSString)